# share same uploads directory with two laravel 5 projects

Tags: php, database, file-upload, upload, laravel-5

I am trying to add articles (image and text) on a laravel project and those articles should be displayed in another laravel project .
 The problem is that I am storing the link (public/uploads/image.png) of the image to the same database but when I switch to the second project the pictures are not displayed is there any suggestions on how can I solve this poblem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you store the relative links of the image (the relative link depend on where to call that link), for examples:

Your relative link: public/uploads/image.png in domain www.abc.com become

> www.abc.com/public/uploads/image.png

and in domain www.123.com it becomes

> www.123.com/public/uploads/image.png

hence, it points to different places.

The solution here is using absolute url to store your images to database:

> {domain-where-your-images-stored}/public/upload/image.png

It will point to same place regardless of your standpoint

Regards,

Comment: I used 123/public/{{$article->image}} but it does not work

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand my point, the absolute url is something like this: `http://www.example.com/public/upload/image.png`. And if you stored the whole absolute links to your database, you can simply use <img src="{{ $article->image }}" />

Comment: <img src="{{ $article->image }}" />  doesnt display the  images on the second project

Comment: what url did you stored in the database?

Comment: Ah, again uploads/imagex.png is relative link. What are your 2 domain names using in projects? what is the domain name store the uploads directory?

Comment: im not using any domains yet , im working locally like this first_app.app (in public/uploads i store my images) and the second is scond_app.app

Comment: then in your second app, `<img src="http://first_app.app/public/{{ $article->image }}" />` should work